# cant retrieve token from headers node

Tags: node.js

I'm having trouble getting the token once the user has logged in. I am supposed to get the token that is generated when I login through req.header so that when I ask for a route in the api (thunder api client) it should be able to give me access

My auth middleware:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.headers['auth-token']
  console.log(token)
  res.json({
    token: token
  })
}
```

My routes:

```
const { Router } = require('express');
const router = Router();

const { 
    getAllUsers,
    signupUser,
    signinUser
} = require('../controllers/user.controller');
const auth = require('../middleware/auth');

router.get('/users', auth, getAllUsers);
router.post('/users/signup', signupUser);
router.post('/users/signin', signinUser);

module.exports = router;
```

when I user users/signin the response header:
[image]

Comment: well,  the header name is 'auth-token'  so it is on req.headers['auth-token'],
but you are using a non-standard header that might trigger a cors issue.

Comment: Hi, I had tried that and req.header('auth-token') but I get undefined in all cases

Comment: you need to deeply log the request and check what is going on.

Comment: thanks, i did log the object header but the auth-token does not appears. It is as if I first make the login request and then when I look for the route that calls the token verifier, the auth-token is not in the headers

Answer (score -2):

Well well well, Apparently my problem was the following:
When I consumed by (thunder client) the route /users/signin -> it returned the object with the token. What I don't realize is that when I request the route that I want to be restricted to logged in users (only with the token) I must pass the same token that I get back from the signin in the headers of the new request (XD !) as seen in the photo.

[image]